# Why doesn't my mod rewrite rule work?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to beautify a url to go from something ugly like:

```
www.domain.com/lookup.php?firstname=jack&middlename=ron&lastname=paul
```

to

```
www.domain.com/n/jack/ron/paul
```

I have some other rewrites working on the server, but this one doesn't seem to like me as I get a 404. Here is what I'm trying:

```
RewriteRule ^/n/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ lookup.php?firstname=$1&middlename=$2&lastname=$3
```

What am I missing? Why doesn't that work?

Something more simple like this works fine:

```
RewriteRule ^article/(.*)$ articles.php?article_id=$1
```

What more needs to be done to do one more complex?

Comment: Looks like the first slash doesn't need to be there. Try changing `^/n/` to `^n/`. Incidentally, you may also want to escape your slashes like this: `\/`. [Test here](http://rubular.com/r/yXtQKroADZ).

Comment: @showdev that beginning forward slash!!! I feel stupid.

Comment: Don't feel stupid. Those things can be complicated. I often find that [regex tool](http://rubular.com/) helpful. Here's a [testing tool](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) specific to .htaccess.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! to me regex is a nightmare. your comment fixed the problem - cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't working because you have rules in an htaccess file. When URI's are processed by rewrite rules in an htaccess file, the leading slash (or the "prefix") is always stripped. That means:

```
# here-------v
RewriteRule ^/n/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ lookup.php?firstname=$1&middlename=$2&lastname=$3
```

The leading slash in your pattern causes it to never match, since all URI's in an htaccess file have it stripped off. Rewrite rules in an htaccess file is essentially like rules within a `<Directory>` container. Try getting rid of that slash.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to see more of your httpd config but here are a few notes:

1. You don't seem to have [L,R] or [L,R=301] or [L,R=302] at the end of your rule (the L if this is the Last rule in the segment which I suspect it is).
2. Your .* regular expressions may be too greedy -- not sure if they will match like you want them to.